# Debug why Dask Dataframe operation is doing nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, dask

I inherited a project using Dask Dataframe to create a dataframe.

```py
from dask import dataframe as dd

# leaving out param values for brevity

df = dd.read_csv(
    's3://some-bucket/*.csv.gz',
    sep=delimiter,
    header=header,
    names=partition_column_names,
    compression=table_compression,
    encoding='utf-8',
    error_bad_lines=False,
    warn_bad_lines=True,
    parse_dates=date_columns,
    dtype=column_dtype,
    blocksize=None,
)

df_len = len(df)

# more stuff
```

I take that Dataframe, process it, and turn it into Parquet.

The process works fine, but *occasionally* (still haven't identified the pattern), the process just hangs on the `len(df)`. No errors, no exiting, nothing.

Is there any concept with Dask Dataframes to have a timeout on a Dataframe operation? Perhaps an option to turn on debugging to get better insight as to what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnostics dashboard provides the most information here. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html has the richest information, but the local schedulers provide some information too (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html).